# Hyperlinked button images not working HTML

Tags: html, image, button, href, src

So, i have a table containing 3 hyperlinked images, all of them when clicked take you to the destination but the bottom 2 ***don't actually show the correct image***, and before you say 'You have not got an image called this' I have, i have checked multiple times.  Here is my following code:

```html
<table border=1 align=center>
  <tr>
    <th>More Help</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a target="_blank" href="http//:www.w3schools.com">
        <input type="image" id="W3Schools" position:absolute style="height:100px; width:150px;" src="./Images/W3SchoolsButton.PNG">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!--This is repeated 2 times but just changing the src and href.-->
```

This is only the first one, that has been repeated but i have changed HREF and SRC, the result in it is that the first one works with an image but the last 2 come up with a typical image clip art and the word 'submit'

Help!

Comment: HTML forbids input elements inside anchors. Image inputs are for sending the coordinates of a click to the server, it makes no sense to have one here. Just use a regular image. `<a href="..."><img src="..." alt="..."></a>`

Comment: *i have checked multiple times*  — Have you checked by looking in the Net tab of your developer tools and confirming that you aren't getting any 404 errors on the page?

Comment: Why don't you try absolute pathing the image to your server in the example here? `src="http://yourdomain.com/Images/W3SchoolsButton.PNG"` - that would show definitively that the image exists where you think it does.

Comment: Quentin, ive just got rid of the input, and id. This does not work, only make it worse. Now instead of a button it is a string link of the destination.                Stuart, i have also just tried this and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an `input` tag inside your `a`? Just use a `img` tag.

The `href` is invalid; it should be `http://www.w3schools.com`, with the colon before the double slashes.

`position: absolute` should go into the style tag.

And is the image source correct? Relative to this file, is the image folder in the same folder or up one folder?

Here's your fixed up code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <img id="W3Schools"  style="height:100px; width:150px; position:absolute;" src="Images/W3SchoolsButton.PNG"> <-- for in the same folder
</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <img id="W3Schools"  style="height:100px; width:150px; position:absolute;" src="../Images/W3SchoolsButton.PNG"> <-- for up one folder
</a>
```